# How to consider a string manipulated as JSON as a dynamic field so it can be unpacked with Kusto

Tags: dynamic, azure-data-explorer, kql

Using Kusto I manipulate a string to I get a JSON formatted output, like:

```
traces 
| where message startswith "XXXXX XXX"
| project Json=substring(message, indexof(message, '{'))
```

This outputs a JSON for each line that I need to unpack with *bag_unpack* but I cannot as the output is not considered a dynamic column:

```
traces 
| where message startswith "Processing Eligibility Process"
| project Json=substring(message, indexof(message, '{'))
| evaluate bag_unpack(Json)
```

> evaluate bag_unpack(): the following error(s) occurred while
> evaluating the output schema: evaluate bag_unpack(): argument #1
> expected to be a reference to a dynamic column

Any idea about how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

[parse_json()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction)

> "Interprets a string as a JSON value and returns the value as dynamic"

```
// Data sample generation. Not part of the solution.
let traces = datatable(message:string)
[
    'Processing Eligibility Process {"a":1, "c":3}'
   ,'Processing Eligibility Process {"c":33, "b":22, "d":{"e":55}}'
];
// Solution starts here.
traces 
| where message startswith "Processing Eligibility Process"
| project Json = parse_json(substring(message, indexof(message, '{')))
| evaluate bag_unpack(Json)
```

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 3 |  |
| 22 | 33 | {"e":55} |  |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4VQsU7DMBTcI%20UfTl6SSBERrboEdYOFASExIlS9JK%20pixtH9gsFlf47dgliAy%20Wz3f37l1V4ZaE4OkwGkbPAzsSbYcrPFjBSE5gt5Adw1szXX7SxLBAHLXssUYX9EKN4fzA3lPPtRenh75Ik%20c0QTjZo7OB6wOIO6N73Wij5QMzjJMiVV%20XUK2ql%20fsIir/F0X2MqgaVS8W4e5UfVKs6tXqHE1ebtKkqvA0x4aXsIzHjh2HFeb4afKJY4Qwh59pRy07qL8jqCgend1zK7j3YcQ6FuZ5sw%20P3E/NdxE/vZTQQ8fvdvsLZKesKIrow29kJhJGQ/1mGkZqX/PoWXwBo6nkaaIBAAA=)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution

```
// Data sample generation. Not part of the solution.
let traces = datatable(message:string)
[
    'Processing Eligibility Process {"a":1, "c":3} bla bla bla'
   ,'Processing Eligibility Process {"c":33, "b":22, "d":{"e":55}} yada yada yada'
];
// Solution starts here.
traces 
| where message startswith "Processing Eligibility Process"
| extend Json = extract("{.*}", 0, message, typeof(dynamic))
| evaluate bag_unpack(Json)
```

| message | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Processing Eligibility Process {"a":1, "c":3} bla bla bla | 1 |  | 3 |  |
| Processing Eligibility Process {"c":33, "b":22, "d":{"e":55}} yada yada yada |  | 22 | 33 | {"e":55} |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4WPT2uEMBDF74Lf4ZHL6iJru8teLHtrLz2UQo%20llFFnNTT%20wYzdivW7N4pLb21gEuZl3i95cYx7EoKlqjWMgmvuSHRT7/DUCFrqBM0ZUjJsY/rlxvcMC6SjjC1OyJ1fKDUcVGwtFZxY6XRdhL736ntwa/PcNW7WOhEPRhc61UbLgFXGqEgltxFUppLDhNTQtTYLIPofMDsPjpCqZL93Z66SUbFKjsdpwkA5/W6O%20Xbne3GMlzURrLicFiV37NKtyXzvG5dZwpprHbtoKaH%20/pGazfwlXOd4tO6F09w5rgRq3G0nFeEmunIjyNBycw7yoaZKZ2G4uD/J9CSMlIr3vm4p%20whmVPgDwqNJp7MBAAA=)